# How to invert shading on an object?

Tags: shaders

I'd like to invert shading in this sense: When there's a light on an object (e.g. a sphere), where the light is meant to be, it's dark (like a shadow), and where the dark parts are meant to be, it's light. Would love any help whatsoever!

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking but you can give a light a negative power like `-100 W`. Then it spreads darkness.

Comment: Mmmwahhhahahaha!

Comment: @Blunder Thank you! Love this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EEVEE,  you can invert the light-response of a surface using *Shader to RGB*

[image]

Comment: Super interesting! Thank you! This is actually closer to what I want but I wish this feature was in Cycles (not via compositor)

Answer (score 2):

In the compositor, the colors on an object can be inverted. In other words, where the shadow is will be bright and where the light is, it will be dark.

[image]

Details:

1. Create the scene
2. Go into the compositor, enable nodes.
3. Insert an invert node and everything will be inverted.
   [image]
4. To select an object to invert, cryptomatte will be used.
5. Enable cryptomatte in the View Layers Properties
   [image]
6. In the compositor setup nodes as shown below to mask out one of the objects.
   [image]

The Blender 2.92.0 file for this is available here - [image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much!